# Unable to click play button coming on mouseover of WebElement in a WebElement List- using serenity and webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-serenity

I got a list of webelement using xpath = ".//div[@id='list']/ul/li"

now li tag has child tags

```
            <div class="abc-box " tabindex="-1">
<div class="abc-img b-loaded" tabindex="-1" style="background-image: url("/binaries/abc.jpg");">
<a class="game-img__link" data-gameid="1569" tabindex="-1" title="abc" href="/1816/launchSocialGame.do?launch=real" rel="nofollow">abc</a>
</div>
<div class="abc-overlay" tabindex="-1">
<a class="abc-overlay__link" data-gameid="1569" href="/1816/launch.do?launch=real" tabindex="-1" rel="nofollow">Play</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I am  successfully getting `<a>` inside first `<div>/<div>` to verify the `title="abc"`. Now if `title=abc`, I need to click second`<a>` as on mouseover/click on the webelement(image) of the list, play button get overlayed.

code i am using

```
 public void click(String gameName) {
   Webelement list=getDriver().findElement(xpath = ".//div[@id='list']/ul/li");
    Iterator var2 = this.list.iterator();      
    while(var2.hasNext()) {
        WebElement we = (WebElement)var2.next();
        WebElement gameImage= we.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
         if (gameImage.getAttribute("title").toLowerCase().contains(gameName.toLowerCase())) {
            withTimeoutOf(SECONDS_TO_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            (new   WebElement playLink = we.findElement(By.className("abc-overlay__link")); withTimeoutOf(SECONDS_TO_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).waitFor(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(playLink));
            playLink.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
            clickedGame=true;
           break;
        }else{
            clickedGame=false;
        }
    }
}
```

With above code, I am getting exception of timeout on

```
    withTimeoutOf(SECONDS_TO_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).waitFor(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(playLink));
```

Tried many thing to get correct locator of play button but all attempts unsuccessful. I am not able to understand where am I doing wrong.

Please suggest how to click on play button.

Thanks

Comment: So what is your question? Did you get any exception with your code? Do you need better locator? Provide with more details

Comment: @Andersson just edited my Question. I am not able to find play button.

Comment: It's not clear about overlay... Do you have to hover mouse over some `image` element for target `<a>` to be visible? Give some more details

Comment: @Andersson thanks, I got it working now.Yes i click or mouse hover to make it visible the play button.